# Aliquot Sequence does not work with amicable number

Tags: c, math

when I use like n=24 the output is : 36 , 55 , 17 , 1 (work well),but when I use like n=6 or n=28 (amicable number) it make me an infinite loop

Any idea or instruction that can help me !

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main()
{
 int n=24;
 int s=0,i=1;
 while(n!=1)
 {
      while(i<=(n/2))
      {
           if(n%i==0)
           {
                s+=i;
           }
           i++;
      }
      if(s!=0&&s!=n)
      {
           printf("\n%d\n",s);
           n=s;
           s=0;
           i=1;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is formulated in a way which makes it hard to understand what you are asking, but putting together title and text I understand that you are asking: "My program should be computing the aliquot sequence of a number, but it **does not work** correctly, because it I start from an amicable number it gets stuck in an infinite loop."

Well the problem is that you should first check the underlying assumption that an aliquot sequence is not a cycle. Well, that is false. Quoting from Wikipedia:

> Many aliquot sequences terminate at 0, all such sequences necessarily end with a prime number followed by 1 (since the only proper divisor of a prime is 1), followed by 0 (since 1 has no proper divisors).

but immediately after:

> There are a variety of ways in which an aliquot sequence might not terminate:
>
> - A perfect number has a repeating aliquot sequence of period 1. The aliquot sequence of 6, for example, is 6, 6, 6, 6, ...
> - An amicable number has a repeating aliquot sequence of period 2. For instance, the aliquot sequence of 220 is 220, 284, 220, 284, ...
> - A sociable number has a repeating aliquot sequence of period 3 or greater. For instance, the aliquot sequence of 1264460 is 1264460, 1547860, 1727636, 1305184, 1264460, ...
> - Some numbers have an aliquot sequence which is eventually periodic, but the number itself is not perfect, amicable, or sociable. For instance, the aliquot sequence of 95 is 95, 25, 6, 6, 6, 6, ...

So, to me it looks as if your assumption is wrong: you should be detecting loops in order to obtain a terminating condition for your program.